# Double and Float Precision

Tags: python, floating-point, double, precision

`a = 2.3`

`b = a*100`

`print b`

output : `230.0`

`print 2.3*100`

output: `229.99999999999997`

What it seems like that Double and Float multiplication are done differently. Is it?

What is the explanation for the above behaviour?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A quick google search gave me [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Basically, floats are represented in bits(0-1), similar to how numbers that we know are represented with 0-9. A lot of numbers cannot represented accurately that way, similar to how we cannot represent accurately 1/3 in decimal(the regular 0-9).

Comment: How does that explain the difference between the statements?

Answer (score 2):

First, Python only has a single type for floating point numbers, which is float; there is no double type.

Now, I'm not sure why, but your issue seems to come down to the use of `print`.

```
>>> 2.3*100
229.99999999999997
>>> print 2.3*100
230.0
```

That was Python 2.7.10. Interestingly, this does not occur in 3.5.1:

```
>>> 2.3*100
229.99999999999997
>>> print(2.3*100)
229.99999999999997
```

Comment: "*not sure why*":  it's the difference between `str()` and `repr()`

Comment: Thanks. There is only a slight difference between actual intent of the question and your answer. However, this issue happens in JAVA, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using old python 2 because of your `print` statements.  When I run the code you give I get the same result, for both `print` statements:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
>>> a = 2.3
>>> b = a*100
>>> print b
230.0
>>> print 2.3*100
230.0
```

I suspect you are using interactive python.  This is a feature of conversion from floating-point to strings:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
>>> 2.3*100
229.99999999999997
>>> print 2.3*100
230.0
>>> str(2.3*100)
'230.0'
>>> repr(2.3*100)
'229.99999999999997'
```

This illustrates the difference between `str`, which `print` uses, and `repr`, which interactive python uses.